# symfony fields relating to each entity

Tags: symfony

I am displaying a list of purchase orders and each "line item" corresponding to it so its basically nested in a table.

ie:

```
PO#  |  Item  |  Qty Ordered  |    Qty Received  |
 1
        123         20            [form Field]
        345         10            [form field]
 5
        232         5             [form field]
```

What I am trying to do is provide a single (unmapped) field for each line item called "quantity received" which the user will type a number in there and save the form. I currently setup my code to have a few collection types nested. For example, my initial FormType starts with my user. Then users have "PurchaseOrders" so I add a collection type of "PurchaseOrders" (PurchaseOrderType), then inside that PurchaseOrderType I have a collectiontype of PurchaseOrderItems (PurchaseOrderItemType) (these are the line items). In that form type I have a single unmapped field called "quantityReceived" (NumberType).

Everything seems to work fine with the form except I dont have a way to place the correct field in the correct row in the table. In my template I have a nested loop to loop through my PurchaseOrders and their corresponding PurchaseOrderItems for the purpose of displaying data in the table shown below. How can I render the correct form field in line with the data I am already displaying? The problem is that collections create field names using sequential index numbers starting with [0], so that does not correspond to the ID of the "PurchaseOrderItem" so as I am looping through each PurchaseOrderItem i feel like I dont have a reliable way to select the correct form field to place into that row.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that I have resolved this issue by instead of looping through my entities, I loop through my form instead and access the necessary variables for display purposes by using form.fieldName.vars.value.[propertyName]